# Access category within rss2_head hook?

Tags: functions, categories, advanced-custom-fields, rss, feed

Can I access the current category of a category feed with the `rss2_head` hook to add for example itunes tags?

Lets say I have `wordpress.com/catx/feed` I want to get `acf field elements` associated with this specific category.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
function itunes_head() {
        $category = get_the_category();
        $categories = get_category();
        global $post;
        var_dump($categories);
        echo print_r($post);
        echo $categories;
        echo $category;
}
add_filter( 'rss2_head', 'itunes_head' );
```

I am assuming that I somehow can retrieve the `catx` category here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just fetch it from the global query using [get_queried_object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/):

```php
function itunes_head() {
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $category = get_queried_object();

        if ( isset( $category ) ) {
            $acf_category = 'category_' . $category->term_id;

            $field = get_field( 'my_category_field', $acf_category );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, get_queried_object() was what I was looking for!